# How to load an NSMutableArray from another class in COCOA

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nstableview

I've searched a lot about this but i can't get a solution to my problem.
I'll explain this. 
I'm developing an multi-window application (this is my first time) and i want to show the same data in two different windows that contains an NSTableView.

I decided to manage all the data from another window controller that manages both windows (each window has its own controller, for buttons and stuff). When I finally was able to connect all the outlets and data sources and so on to that NSTableViews, my data does not shows.
Debugging my app, i discovered that the data manager class does not get all that information. (I load it from main window class, from a menu item) and when I want to take that info back... it's gone!
Here it is the code:

The .m data manager class:

```
@interface GestionTableView1 ()
@end

@implementation GestionTableView1
@synthesize tableViewGrupo;
@synthesize alumnos;

-(id)init {
    NSLog(@"en init GESTIONTABLEVIEW");
    alumnos = pc.alumnos;
    NSLog(@"alumnos %lu", [alumnos count]);

    return self;
}
```

The main window .m class:

```
-(IBAction)cargarAlumnos:(id)sender
{
    if(gestionAlumnos == nil){
        gestionAlumnos = [[GestionAlumnos alloc]init];
    }
    [gestionAlumnos setAlumnosAleatorios];
    alumnos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    alumnos = [gestionAlumnos getAlumnos];
    NSLog(@"CARGAR ALUMNOS PROTOTIPO %lu", [alumnos count]);
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getAlumnos{
    return alumnos;
}
```

I've proved that the data loads in "cargarAlumnos", but i'm not able to move that information to that "dataManaging" class.

Hope you can help me with this.. :(

Thank you a Lot!

Comment: What is `pc` in `alumnos = pc.alumnos`?  Include it in your `NSLog` and see what the value is.  (Also, you are allocating a `NSMutableArray` and then immediately replacing it with a different one.)

Comment: `IBOutlet PrototIPOControlador *pc;` that is the row. "PrototIPOControlador is the main window controller. Im so frustrated right now and didn't know if was possible that haven't allocated that array could crash the app.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Perhaps you're doing things in the wrong order.  You init your data manager, which gets the array from `pc`, but it seems you don't create the array until after that.

Comment: I think i've find the mistake. I'm trying to access to 2 different instances of that class. How can I access to the same I accessed before?
Thank you again!
EDIT (after your answer)
The thing is that the window always shows before that array can be loaded